# AJAX Script - Now need to update more than one

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have a results table that allows users to delete library books from their list of selected books at the checkout stage. I've implemented a simple AJAX technique so that when the user clicks the Delete button next to a book in the list it removes it from the page without having to reload the page - this is all working well.

I now also need to update another element on the page that handles the pagination showing how many selected books they have. At the top of the list there is this pagination summary:

```
<div class="recordlist_nav">Displaying records 1 - 10 of 10 records selected</div>
```

As well as removing the book from the list I also need to update this, for example if they deleted one book it should change to:

```
<div class="recordlist_nav">Displaying records 1 - 9 of 9 records selected</div>
```

I can generate the updated string but not sure how I get my AJAX script to update multiple elements at the same time. Here's my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function deleteRecord(recid,articleID) {
   // Allocate an XMLHttpRequest object
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      // IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   } else {
      // IE6, IE5
      var xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
   // Set up the readyState change event handler
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if ((this.readyState == 4) && (this.status == 200)) {
         document.getElementById("selectedRecord" + recid).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
      }
   }
   // Open an asynchronous POST connection and send request
   xmlhttp.open("POST", "delete_record.php", true);
   xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
   xmlhttp.send("recid="+recid+"&articleID="+articleID);
   return false;  // Do not follow hyperlink
}
</script>
```

At present the delete_record.php simply echoes out an empty string when it deletes the selected record:

```
$result = '';
echo $result ;
```

I'm storing the updated pagination header in a $navigation variable. I now need to pass this back to the script and have that script replace the contents of the  with the contents of the $navigation variable.

Comment: I admire your purist approach, but using a library like jQuery will hide most of this code and allow you to focus on the actual application (rather than its mechanics).

Comment: Have a look at my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15713646/how-to-structure-javascript-when-including-another-php-file/15713778#15713778 it will put you on the right path.

Comment: Basically you want to fire events to inform parts of your application that something of interest have happened and these application modules/parts/sections whatever will listen to these and react. In your case, when records get deleted, you could have a `recordsdelete` event that gets fired. Then your pagination section would listen to the event and update the DOM accordingly.

Comment: improve this question it's confusing. Do you need help with php too?

Answer (score -1):

+1 to Nick.  Use jQuery for this, it'll make your life waaaaaay simpler.

```
<script><!-- type="text/javascript" not needed -->
function deleteRecord(recid,articleID,thisPage,allPages) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'delete_record.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify({recid:recid,articleID:articleID}),
        success: function () {
            // It worked
            $(".recordlist_nav").text("Displaying records 1 - "+thisPage+" of "+allPages+" records selected");
        }
    });
    return false;
}
</script>
```

Comment: The number of remaining records needs to a variable, the user may hit delete several times.

Comment: Modified to take those in as function parameters too